# Como filtrar un foreach para un <select>

Tags: php

Buenas tardes,

Tengo este código:

```
<div class="modal-body">
<p><?php echo $ee['Establecimiento']; ?> have <?php echo $totalbooks; ?> books.</p>
<p> Do you wish to move all the books to another library?</p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>assets/private/library/establecimiento.php">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ee['IDEstablecimiento']; ?>" name="id" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="move"/>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select class="form-control" name="tothis" required>
        <?php foreach ($establecimiento as $gg): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $gg['IDEstablecimiento']; ?>"><?php echo $gg['Establecimiento']; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn sbold green-jungle cold-md-4"> Move and Suspend </button>
</div>
</form>

<p>Or you can also suspend the library and leave the books in it</p>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>assets/private/library/establecimiento.php">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ee['IDEstablecimiento']; ?>" name="id" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="suspend"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn sbold red-thunderbird"> Suspend </button>
</form>
```

Básicamente lo que hace es para poder eliminar un establecimiento, mira si existen libros asignados a ese establecimiento, en caso positivo me abre un modal (el código de arriba) y da la opción de darlo de baja con los libros en el establecimiento, o traspasar los libros a otro establecimiento.

En el select, te lista los establecimientos. Bueno, la pregunta es (estoy muy perdido con esto) como no mostrar el establecimiento principal (dle cual se van a trasladar los libros a otro) ya que no tiene sentido trasladar los libros al mismo establecimiento.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de como filtrar el foreach y no mostrar el establecimiento que se esta eliminando?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El nombre del establecimiento lo tienes al principio `$ee['Establecimiento'];` y dentro del `foreach` tienes `$gg['Establecimiento']`

Dentro del `foreach` puedes crear un `if`

```
<?php foreach ($establecimiento as $gg): ?>
   <? if ($ee['Establecimiento'] != $gg['Establecimiento']) ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $gg['IDEstablecimiento']; ?>"><?php echo $gg['Establecimiento']; ?></option>
   ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Al recorrer los establecimientos la condicion que agregue, seria verificar si el nombre del establecimiento que estas recorriendo es distinto al que tienes, carga los selectores disponibles.

Comment: No había pensado yo en eso jaja Muchas gracias!

Comment: @CharlieClewer si soluciona tu problema, recuerda marcar mi respuesta :D

Comment: sisi, es que tenia el cooldown para marcar la respuesta :) ya esta!